# "Access to OData is disabled" error when making a Graph API call to a calendar

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have a demo integration running from ServiceNow to Office 365, everything was working fine last time I checked (it was a couple days ago). I have set it up in two ways (using two Auth flows):

1. Authorization Code - this still works fine.
2. Client Credentials - this is giving me an error now when I try to access any calendar. The App is registered, the permissions are there:

   [image]

When trying to run the getSchedule API, I get the below response:

```
"error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access to OData is disabled.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "e14a6800-ed63-4692-9934-cc0ec009d93b",
      "date": "2020-03-16T14:43:34"
    }
}
```

I checked everywhere I could. The Access token is generated. It is definitely something to do with the Graph API for the calendar.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with the Application Access Policy.

Basically, if you use Application Permissions within OAuth for Microsoft 365, you can further narrow down the permissions using the below instructions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access

> Microsoft Graph application permissions (you may not need all of
> them):
>
> - Mail.Read
> - Mail.ReadBasic
> - Mail.ReadBasic.All
> - Mail.ReadWrite
> - Mail.Send
> - MailboxSettings.Read
> - MailboxSettings.ReadWrite
> - Calendars.Read
> - Calendars.ReadWrite
> - Contacts.Read
> - Contacts.ReadWrite
>
> For more information about configuring application access policy, see the PowerShell cmdlet reference for [`New-ApplicationAccessPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-applicationaccesspolicy?view=exchange-ps&preserve-view=true).
>
> ## Handling API errors
>
> You might encounter the following error when an API call is denied
> access due to a configured application access policy.
>
> ```
> {
> "error": {
>     "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
>     "message": "Access to OData is disabled.",
>     "innerError": {
>         "request-id": "<request GUID is here>",
>         "date": "<UTC date format here>"
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> If the Microsoft Graph API calls from your app return this error, work
> with the Exchange Online administrator for the organization to ensure
> that your app has permission to access the mailbox resource.

It appears in our case one of the policies was not removed/updated properly. After we removed all policies related to this integration, it started working again.

Comment: what policies? example?